# In Unity, .MoveTowards reaches a distance squared of 0, but .Lerp does not. Why?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Here is my update function:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Type == FollowType.MoveTowards)
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _currentPoint.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    if (Type == FollowType.Lerp)
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, _currentPoint.Current.position, Time.deltaTime * Speed);

    // Move _currentPoint to next point
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        var distanceSquared = (transform.position - _currentPoint.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distanceSquared == 0)
            _currentPoint.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

I'm moving two objects, one using `.MoveTowards`, and another using `.Lerp`.

I allow them to move to the next position when space is pressed and their distance squared to the reached position is equal to 0. `.MoveTowards` has no problem with this, but it seems that `.Lerp` never reaches a distance squared of 0, thus not allowing the object to move to the next position.

But if I use a margin, I can get `.Lerp` to work, including `.MoveTowards` of course.

Example:

```
        if (distanceSquared < .1f * .1f)
            _currentPoint.MoveNext();
```

Why do I need to use this margin? I've seen others do this as well, but I still haven't grasped the concept.

I appreciate any knowledge on the matter! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly because that's not what lerp *does*. "Linear interpolation" takes two values and returns another value that is `t` percent between them. If you never pass in a `t` of zero or one, you'll never see either endpoint represented in the output.

Typically, you might pass in a `t` that increases over time. For example, you could have a float named `timer` that increases by [`Time.deltaTime`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) each frame:

```
float timer;
Vector3 startPosition = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 endPosition = Vector3.up * 10f;

//move from "startPosition" to "endPosition" over 20 seconds
void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, timer / 20f);
}
```

In your case, you're keeping `t` more or less constant. It'll be roughly equal to `Speed` times `0.02` or so. By repeatedly moving your `startPosition` closer to `endPosition`, you'll produce an interesting easing effect -- because your output will always be, say, 10% closer -- but that's also exactly why your output never reaches its target value.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks. My problem was misunderstanding linear interpolation. I began to use it for its easing effect, when really the effect appeared from not understanding it entirely!